# DocBook to OOXML

Tags: xslt, ms-word, openxml, docbook

Our users are asking for a simple way to convert DocBook XML to OOXML (DocBook to Word DOCX) and back. The editing in house is done in [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/docbook_editor.html) but sometimes they have to send files for editing to other people and Word is still the de facto standard.

I imagine this will be a major undertaking so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Found [docbook2wordml](http://www.explain.com.au/oss/docbook/index.html) XSL stylesheets. This could be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294495/docbook-to-word-conversion ?

Answer (score 4):

Try Oxgarage: http://www.tei-c.org/oxgarage/ it converts between DocBook and OOXML (and other formats) via TEI.

You can use it as a web service, or you can get the XSLT 2.0 scripts here: https://github.com/TEIC/Stylesheets/

Edit: updated links!

Comment: Seems like a great service. I've stuck with docbook2wordml stylesheets. After many bug fixes they seem to do the job.

Comment: Both links are down. The TEI stylesheets are now probably [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tei/files/Stylesheets/)

Answer (score 0):

OxGarage http://oxgarage.oucs.ox.ac.uk:8080/ege-webclient/ seems down.

Alternatively, you can get up running your own OxGarage service using [the OxGarage docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/teic/oxgarage/), which should be the preferable way.

Also you could try building an OxGarage docker image yourself using [this oxgarage-docker GutHub repo](https://github.com/yucigou/oxgarage-docker). Once it's up running, then you can use the OxGarage web client in your browser:

```
http://<your host name e.g., localhost>:8080/ege-webclient
```

[image]